# How to change your full name for Yahoo Profile?

Tags: yahoo

It's very annoying as it seems there is no place to change your full name appearing in your Yahoo Profile.

URL: https://edit.yahoo.com/mc2.0/eval_profile

Sample screenshot:

[image: Full name in profile]

I've read that you can change the full name for Sending Name for e-mail by going to *Mail* → *Settings* → *Accounts* and **Edit**. But above full name seems to be fixed.

Any idea how to change it?

Clicking on *Edit profile details* is redirecting me to my public profile and from there, when trying to edit anything, usually I'm redirected back to this form again.